# mySQL Multiple Joins in 1 Statement Only Shows Attribute Headings

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to pull from three different tables with inner join but whenever I run it the result just shows the headings of each attribute of each column. Does anyone know how to fix this and thank you for any help.

```
select dvd.dvd_id, dvd.dvd_title, rentalprices.daily_charge, dvd.no_of_discs, dvd.age_rating, publisher.publisher_name, distribution_company.company
From dvd
    inner join rentalprices
        on dvd.rental_rate_id=rentalprices.daily_charge
    inner join publisher
        on dvd.publisher_id=publisher.publisher_name
    inner join distribution_company
        on dvd.dist_comp_id=distribution_company.company;
```

As well as this if all inner joins are changed to left joins rental prices works but the others are left null.

Comment: Are you sure you want an inner join?  What happens when you do a join?  It seems odd to me that the `dvd.publisher_id` would match the `publisher.publisher_name`.  Are you sure you have the correct columns?

Comment: The reason is that there are zero result rows.

Comment: As @dstudeba pointed out, it looks like the columns your joining are somewhat peculiar. Not sure who your architect is, but typically you want FK and PKs to have the same name.. ex: `on dvd.publisher_id=publisher.publisher_id` .. I mean unless your publisher_id is for example `foo` and your publisher_name is also `foo` but this is typically bad practice.

Comment: Well, when they are all changed to normal joins there is no change. As for the architect, not a lot I can really say

Answer (score 0):

If you say that "As well as this if all inner joins are changed to left joins rental prices works but the others are left null", than you already gave the answer to your question:

If, as you wrote, a statement like `dvd left join publisher on dvd.publisher_id = publisher.publisher_name` gives you only `null`-values on the `publisher` table's attributes, then this means that none of the `dvd.publisher_id` values matches any `publisher.publisher_name`. If you then use an inner join, the result must be empty, since there won`t be any matches, too.

Note that any further inner join or left join will not add any rows to the result; if one of the tables or join results that participate in other inner joins or as lhs of left joins is empty, then the result remains empty.

So: have a look at the semantics / the contents of the attributes in use.